# RC522 not writing with raspberry pi

Tags: gpio, nfc

So I am new to this, I followed this tutorial https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/ and did exactly what they said in it. It looks like my RC522 isnt detecting any RFID card. Is there any solution to this, what are the possible problems, and is there any way to see which pins are being used, or where could this go wrong?

Comment: can you confirm SPI is enabled? confirm your wiring? confirm your code is correct? confirm you actually have a RC522 reader. confirm you have a RFID card compatible with the RC522 reader

Comment: I can confirm i have RC522 reader and card that is compatible, as well as enabled SPI, and correct code. I am not 100% sure about wiring. I am doing everything on Raspberry Pi 3 B+